# how to keep scroll bar always to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

to keep scroll bar always at the bottom of the page i used

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {

        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast"); 
    });
});
```

It is working in the Firefox but it is not working in the chrome.
Why it is not working in the chrome can anybody suggest me the good solution to keep the scroll bar always at the bottom of the page.

*Thanks for any help*

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Do you want the scrollbar to stick to the bottom of the page so that if the user moves it, it moves back down? Or just at start up. I'm using chrome and this code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/RHSFR/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move back to the bottom of the page even if the user attempts to scroll up, you are going to need to call your function on an interval.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function scrollBottom(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
    }

    setInterval(scrollBottom, 500);

});
```

You can play with the interval to get the desired amount of UI interactivity.

Alternatively, you could bind to the scroll event, this will fire whenever the user scrolls.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
    });

});
```